# How to call Activity class method from another Activity class

Tags: android

My MainActivity class is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UserInterface_Main  UIMain = new UserInterface_Main();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UIMain.ExpendableListView();
}
```

The another Activity class is:

```
public class UserInterface_Main extends Activity{

ExpandableListView exv;

public void ExpendableListView()
{

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.elv1);
    exv.setAdapter(new MAdapter(context));
}
```

Now tell me how to call `ExpendableListView()` method from `MainActivity` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

You probably want to also implement a UI element in your activity_main.xml to trigger the transfer. Perhaps you ought to add a button and use android:onCLick in xml.

ie.

{xml}

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:text="coolbutton" 
       android:onClick="blah"  />
```

{MainActivity.java}

```
public void blah(View view){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call an activity from another activity (not the main activity), you have to sepcify the context :

```
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
```